# Dynamic sum ranges while adding rows above first row and below last row

Tags: sum, offset, excel-indirect

I have sample numerical data from A2 to A5. The sum is displayed in A6. I wish to hold the range as dynamic while summing. Hence, I used the following formula in A6

```
=SUM(A2:OFFSET(A6,-1,0))
```

The above formula considers extra rows that are added below A5 only. If I add cells above A2, they are not being considered in the calculation of sum. How should the formula be modified in order to consider the rows above A2 also in the sum?

**Note:**  I am aware that `=SUM(INDIRECT("A6:A"&ROW()-1))` is a solution to this problem. But, the difficultly I am facing is that, when I copy this sum formula to a different cell, the reference  inside the quotes has to be modified manually. Hence, I desire a formula such that I need not modify the reference cells manually each time when I copy the SUM formula.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this formula and it works

```
=SUM(A1:OFFSET(A6,-1,0))
```

I am posting this for the benefit of the community. As explained previously, even though `=SUM(INDIRECT("A6:A"&ROW()-1))` is a solution to the problem, one has to edit the reference manually, which is cumbersome. I hope this helps others in this forum.

**Note:** Select one cell above the first cell from which sum is to be calculated